# Why $\alpha I +A$ can improve the condition nubmer of a SPD matrix $A$?

Tags: finite-difference, condition-number

For Poisson equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions in 2 dimension:
$$
-\Delta u=f,
$$
using **FDM (centered difference) or FEM** discretization, we can obtain a **SPD** system of linear equations as follows:
$$
Ax=b.
$$
And if the step size is $h$, then the spectral condition number of matrix $A$ is $O(h^{-2})$.

A conclusion goes that "Given a positive constant $\alpha>0$, then matrix $\alpha I+A$ is well-conditioned". Why the addition of a positive term $\alpha$ to the main diagonal of matrix $A$ can improve the condition number of matrix $A$?

Because in my opinion, the new matrix condition number is

$$
\mathrm{cond}_2(\alpha I+A) = \frac{\alpha+\lambda_{\max}(A)}{\alpha+\lambda_{\min}(A)}>\frac{\lambda_{\max}(A)}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}=\mathrm{cond}_2(A).
$$

But the numerical results contrast as follows:

```matlab
clc;clear;
n=10;
A=gallery('poisson',n);
cond(full(A))

n=10;
A=gallery('poisson',n);
cond(full(A)+speye(n^2))

n=20;
A=gallery('poisson',n);
cond(full(A)+speye(n^2))
```

The numerical results as follows:

```matlab
ans =

   48.3742


ans =

    7.6056


ans =

    8.5723
```

As is seen, the condition number of $I+A$ is less than $A$ (48.3742 > 7.6056).

Furthermore, when the system size increases, the condition number almost do not increase (from 7.6056 to 8.5723), which seems that the condition number of matrix $\alpha I+A$ is independent on $h$. Why this happens? Does it really independent on step size $h$?

Comment: You don't need to thank in your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inequality $\frac{\alpha + \lambda_{max}(A)}{\alpha+\lambda_{min}(A)} > \frac{\lambda_{max}(A)}{\lambda_{min}(A)}$ doesn't hold because $\lambda_{max}(A) > 1 > \lambda_{min}(A) > 0$ and $\alpha > 0$. In fact, the reverse inequality holds in this case. Hence, there is no contradiction here.

EDIT: From the comments, I realized that the question is not answered completely yet.

Also,
$\kappa(A+\alpha I) = \frac{\alpha + \lambda_{max}(A)}{\alpha+\lambda_{min}(A)} = \frac{\frac{\alpha}{\lambda_{max}(A)}+1}{\frac{\alpha}{\lambda_{max}(A)}+\frac{\lambda_{min}(A)}{\lambda_{max}(A)}} = \frac{\frac{\alpha}{\lambda_{max}(A)}+1}{\frac{\alpha}{\lambda_{max}(A)}+O(h^2)}$.

Hence, for small enough $h$ and big enough $\alpha$, we have $\kappa(A) \approx 1+\frac{\lambda_{max}(A)}{\alpha}$. One can see that $\lambda_{max}(A)$ changes very little. For example,

```
poisson = @(n) full(gallery('poisson',n,n));
max(abs(eig(poisson(10))))
```

ans =

7.837971894457977

```
max(abs(eig(poisson(40))))
```

ans =

7.988263204734964

```
max(abs(eig(poisson(60))))
```

ans =

7.994696359539318

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By the way, Is the condition number of $\alpha I+A$ independent on step size $h$? Why? Because in my numerical examples,  when the system size increases, the condition number does not increase much.

Comment: MATLAB's gallery() with the 'poisson' arguement returns a matrix with the stencil values (-1,4,-1) and is independent of the number of discretization points or the grid spacing h.  Even if you scale this matrix by multiplying by $1/(h^2)$, both the maximum and minimum eigenvalues get scaled equally and hence, there is no change in the condition number.

Comment: But, the condition number of matrix $A$ is $O(h^{-2})$, why the condition number of $\alpha I+A$ is independent on mesh size? I cannot understand it, can you give me some more details or some proof? Thanks.

Comment: You are right about the condition number depending on $h$. Check the answer again. I added a "proof".